# How to return an aggregate initializer as templated struct?

Tags: c++

I want to return an aggregate initializer when the return value is templated:

```
Msg {
  std::string msgId;
  std::string data; 
};

template <typename T> 
struct RetVal {
  int code;
  std::optional<T> msg;
};
 
RetVal<Msg> fn1() {
  Msg msg{.msgId = "123", .data = "my data"}; // C99 Designator initialization

  return { 200, msg };
}

RetVal<Msg> fn2() {
  Msg msg{.msgId = "456", .data = "my other data"}; // C99 Designator initialization

  return { 200, msg };
}
```

the MSVC compiler outputs:

> 'return': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to RetVal
> MSVC(C2440)

by the way...
can I return with some of the fields undefined? like the following:

example 1:

```
return {, resp};
```

example 2:

```
return {code, };
```

is it possible?

My compiler is the latest MSVC 19.27.

Comment: Looks like at least C++17 is required for this.

Comment: yes, the cmake configuration has:    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON).  I will try what you suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is valid in c++20, and should be compiled by a conformant compiler.

---

Yes, you can return a `Retval<Msg>` with some of the fields missing, like this:

```
return { .code = 200 };
// or  
return { .msg = msg };
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zrobKx) that compiles with `/std:c++latest`.